# Same publicPath when loading images from css and html files

Tags: webpack

To make it simple, I have:

```
|   index.html
+---css
|       style.css
+---img
    |   image.jpg
```

In style.css:
`background: url("../img/image.jpg")`

In index.html:
`<img src="img/image.jpg">`

And I basically want the same in the output, but instead, for the css I get:
`background: url("img/image.jpg")`

So it doesn't work because the css is not in the same folder as the index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this issue, I had to set `publicPath: '../'` to the css rule.